# Unitary property of scattering matrix

Tags: rf, s-parameters, reflection

From [s-parameter lossless network definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_parameters#Lossless_networks) , The sum of the incident powers at all ports is equal to the sum of the reflected powers at all ports.

[image]

But how do we derive the above unitary property expression involving S22 and S21 ?

Comment: For context, can you link to where you saw this equation? What does the additional \$\ell\$ subscript indicate?

Comment: Do you want to know why the S-matrix for a lossless system is unitary? or do you want to know why the matrix being unitary leads to the equation you quoted?

Comment: @ThePhoton I am trying to derive the quoted equation under page 133 or section 4.2.1 Forward-Wave Directional Couplers inside the book "[RF and Microwave Coupled-Line Circuits](http://booksdescr.org/item/index.php?md5=92FEE3E65A74300C2C483211F8B38B8F)" written by Rajesh Mongia and Prakash Bhartia